# My button is not showing up

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uistoryboard

My login page includes a login button and scroll view.
When I run the program the login button is not showing up. Only the images in my scroll view are visible. The button is clickable even if it is not visible. I mean if I click on the area where button is supposed to be placed, it works even if I cannot see the button.

I'm loading images like below:

```
- (void)preparePageControl {
    _imageArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"picture1", @"picture2", @"picture3", nil];

    for (int i = 0; i < [_imageArray count]; i++) {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[_imageArray objectAtIndex:i]];

        [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];
    }

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * [_imageArray count], self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self preparePageControl];
}
```

Design Time View:

[image: Storyboard view]

When I try to bring the button upper layer, Editor/Arrange/Sent to front menu is disabled.

[image]
What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you using auto layout, are your constraints set up correctly? Try logging the location of the button when you touch it, to get an idea where it is currently at or if it is really just a display issue!

Comment: It's in the same place where it's being in story board. x=100, y=319

Comment: and I don't use auto layout

Comment: Okay, it may be that your scrollView is overlaying it, can you post a screenshot of the running app, where images are displayed!?

Comment: @zontragon : hide those buttons for some moment and try again...

Comment: I've made them hidden. They are now invisible and not clickable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your second screenshot the button is actually *behind* the scrollView, try moving the button to the front by selecting it in the storyboard and choosing **Editor -> Arrange -> Send to Front**. Or choose the scrollView and choose **Editor -> Arrange -> Send to Back**

[image]

If that does not work, drag the `Login` button and the `Register` button lower than the `Scroll View`. Your current order is Login - Register - Scroll View. You need to change it to Scroll View - Login - Register. That dragging has to be performed in the area directly left of the `Arrange` in your 3rd screenshot.

Comment: I've tried to do this but the menu is disabled. I've added the picture to my question.

Comment: @zontragon I provided another solution, please check that one as well.

Comment: @zontragon you are welcome. I have no idea why sometimes you cannot do it via the menu and have to do it "by hand", but at least there is another way :)